# Prevent shape drawable from scaling

Tags: android, layer-list

I have a layer list that I intend to apply on a radiobutton.

This is the XML

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <corners android:radius="30dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="5dp"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="55dp"
    android:top="5dp">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
        <size
            android:width="10dp"
            android:height="10dp"></size>
    </shape>
</item>
```

This is how it appears

[image]

It appears fine on my radio button until i use wrap content. 
If i apply a width parameter to the radio button the circle scales . How should I stop that from happening?

[image]

Comment: Show your RadioButton in XML

Comment: use nine patch drawable in such case

Answer (score -1):

There is a width and height attribute that we can present to the  tag too. This ensures that the item once placed in its container (RadioButton etc) doesn't exceed the given width height.

```
    <item
    android:bottom="5dp"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="55dp"
    **android:width="10dp"
    android:height="10dp"**
    android:top="5dp">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
        <size
            android:width="10dp"
            android:height="10dp"></size>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Android studio says the `height` attribute is only available from API 23.